# How to make a custom python class to support memoryview conversion

Tags: python

Is it possible for a custom class to implement `memoryview(obj)`?

For example,

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = b'sdfajsdfjkasdf'

    def __memoryview__(self):
        return self.b
```

so that

```py
a = A()
mv = memoryview(a) # returns the memoryview of a.b
```

is a valid operation.

Comment: No.  The parameter to `memoryview` has to be a bytes string.  It's mostly designed for classes written in C.

Comment: The type must implement the buffer protocol, which would require an extension type (i.e. defined in C)

Comment: @TimRoberts: `memoryview` takes plenty of things that aren't bytestrings. For example, you can pass it a NumPy array. The memoryview type actually has a ton of features that don't make sense at all for bytestrings, like shape and stride info, mostly to support types like NumPy arrays.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - yeah, my goal is to create a placeholder class that mimics a NumPy array, and I use its`memoryview` interface extensively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[On Python 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-688-making-the-buffer-protocol-accessible-in-python), you'll be able to implement [`__buffer__`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-buffer-types):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = b'sdfajsdfjkasdf'

    def __buffer__(self, flags):
        return self.b.__buffer__(flags)
```

`memoryview(a)` will then delegate to `__buffer__`. (You can also implement `__release_buffer__` if your object needs to perform any cleanup when a buffer is released.)

Before 3.12, there's no support. `memoryview` [only accepts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memory-views) arguments that support the buffer protocol, and before 3.12, the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) is C-only. There are no Python-level hooks before 3.12.

Before 3.12, the closest you can get to defining memoryview conversion is defining a class that *subclasses* an existing class with buffer support, but that will make your objects actually *be instances* of that existing class. For example, if you make your class a subclass of `bytes`, then `memoryview(a)` will create a memoryview over your object. It will *not* create a memoryview of `a.b`, and there will be all sorts of usually-undesirable side effects. Do not do this just to provide memoryview support; use `memoryview(a.b)`.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation of what's going on behind the scene. I missed buffer protocol documentation while I was researching